# linq using timestamp column to filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a sqlserver table that has a timestamp column, I'm trying tou use it for filter a linq query like this:

```
byte[] filtroTimeStamp = SessionBag.Current.mesasTimeStamp; 

var ubicAbiertas = from uA in db.TableA
    select uA;

ubicAbiertas = ubicAbiertas.Where(
     y => y.BitAbierta == true 
   & y.BitBloqueada == true 
   & y.TimeStampUltimoCambio == filtroTimeStamp);
```

When I try this way it shows an error:
operator & can't be applied to operands of type bool and byte[]

How can  I do to use Byte[] values as a filter of linq Query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be && (two not one ampersand), e.g.

```
&& y.BitBloqueada == true
```

Comment: It throws the same message

Comment: && y.TimeStampUltimoCambio == filtroTimeStamp

Comment: and is that really a byte[] ?

Comment: did you add in the second && ?  so what type is TimeStampUltimoCambio ?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have another 3 filter now I update all & with &&. Tks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20887/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-dove)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [&& operator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=LwvGUMfNHsHi4QSRgYGYCA&usg=AFQjCNGeR1L3L_RCqlMOdAMudPserpIkpw) which performs a logical-AND:

```
ubicAbiertas = ubicAbiertas.Where(y => y.BitAbierta == true 
                                  && y.BitBloqueada == true
                                  && y.TimeStampUltimoCambio == filtroTimeStamp);
```

Comment: It throws the same message

Comment: Are you sure you applied the && operator?

Comment: yes but must to modofy all other operatos even thea aren't byte[]